# Android - How to stop animation between activity changes

Tags: android, animation, android-intent, flags

I have multiple different Activity in my app and I don't want any transition animation when changing between Activities.  Below is the how I'm changing between Activities:

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
            startActivity(i);
```

This works great the first time I start a new Activity.  There is no animation, but when I go back to an Activity that is already started it seems like the "Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION" is ignored and the default animation happens.

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Have you tried [`overridePendingTransition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int,%20int))?

Comment: No I hadn't tried 'overridePendingTransition(0,0)'.  I used that in each Activities onResume() and onPause().  It worked perfect. 

Thanks!!!

Comment: It helped me on my Nexus 7 but it did not on my SGS4. Is there any other way to fix this ? Thanks.

Comment: @oleg.semen: Try the theme approach from [another answer on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18973007/115145).

Answer (score 18):

You can set FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT by code and FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION in manifest as below:

Create noAnimTheme in res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="noAnimTheme" parent="android:Theme">
   <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
</style>
```

or

```
<style name="noAnimTheme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar">
   <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
</style>
```

and use it in manifest:

```
<activity android:name="SecondActivity" android:theme="@style/noAnimTheme"/>
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

I wa needing this as I had to create activities on clicking the menus.

I did the following :

I added the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION` flag to the intent. It stopped the animations while creating the activity for the first time.

However the activities in the stack which were called when we click on the same menu again (probably from a different activity), it had the animation.

So I added `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` to clear or rather finish the activity when it starts a new activity. This caused to create a new activity (without animation) when I click on the menu once again.

Comment: But isnt this wrong "making no animation" fix, while allowing the activitie still being created?

Comment: I believe bringing the activity from the back stack without animation, might be the best possible solution around.

Answer (score 3):

add this after creating the second intent

```
        Intent i = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(i);
```

when you return to the first intent, animation is disabled, worked for me though

Answer (score 1):

If you're using FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT then you can also override onNewIntent for later startActivity calls. This will just work for bring to front states instead of first call.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.whatever, R.anim.whatever);
}
```

Sure, you must implement this in target activity.