# How to stop animations between switching activities?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-transitions

I am developing an android app. There are two activities in the app. In the action bar, i have one button which opens the another activity. But when i click on the button the default android animation takes place between switching the activity. I tried using `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);` and `overridePendingTransition(0, 0);` but to no avail. This method is not working. Min sdk of my app is 10.

**What I want.**

I want that there should be no animation when i click on the button.

**My Code**

```
@Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
            {
                MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
                menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
            {         
                switch (item.getItemId())
                {
                case R.id.action_button1:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);

            }
                return true;

        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [switching activities without animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972295/switching-activities-without-animation) and [Android - How to stop animation between activity changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670754/android-how-to-stop-animation-between-activity-changes)

Comment: dhke its not duplicarte of that question. Solution given in that question is not working for me.

Comment: Maybe better if you can post your code for others to have a better understanding.

Comment: tibzon i added my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `finish()` and then trying to override the animation by adding flags to the intent. You have to add the flag to the intent before you use it in `startActivity()`. Try this instead of your code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(0,0); //0 for no animation
finish();
```

Or:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(0,0); //0 for no animation
```

If for some reason `Inteng.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` or `finish()` aren't working for you, try to set `android:noHistory=true` for your `<activity>` in `Manifest.xml`. See [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestActivity_noHistory).

Comment: Its working but i want the FirstActivity to be closed when SecondActivity is opened.

Comment: When i call finish(), animation is again taking place but when i don't call finish(), its working fine.

Comment: @Faiyaz Try `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`

Comment: {intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);} not working

Comment: @Faiyaz In what way isn't it working? Try the most recent edit involving changes to your manifest file.

Comment: When i call finish(), animation is shown and when i dont call finish() animation is not shown.

Comment: Its now working man. That android:nohHistory method actually worked. Thanks. Marking your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
protected static void start_Activity(Context context, Class<? extends Activity> activity) {
        if (context.getClass() == activity) { // current activity: do nothing
            return;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, activity);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);      
        ((Activity) context).finish();
        context.startActivity(intent);
        ((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(0, 0);        
    }
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "vn.com.abuabi.animation"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

Mainifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="vn.com.abuabi.animation" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_second" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity:

```
package vn.com.abuabi.animation;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void doChange(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);        
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }
}
```

SecondActivity:

```
package vn.com.abuabi.animation;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;


public class SecondActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_second, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void doChange(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }
}
```

2 layout files:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="vn.com.abuabi.animation.SecondActivity">

    <TextView android:text="Second" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="doChange"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="doChange"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have succesfully tested my app (min sdk 16) in emlulator API 16

Comment: Actually my app min sdk is 10.

Comment: Have you tried to run on other emulators (different APIs)?

Comment: I am running it on real device. One with android 2.3, another with 4.0.1 and another with 4.1.2

Comment: I have built new app (Min sdk 10), tested on emulator 4.1 (api 16), no animation, no need "noHistory". I'll show you my new app code :)

Comment: That would be great. :)