# Is there any need for this code in my project?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-sqlite

I have commented a few lines of code out in this function as I'm not sure what their purpose is. However when I run my android application everything work perfectly... so i assume I do not need them and they serve no purpose in my project.

```
private void deleteRoutine() {
    myDb.deleteRoutineForCurrentDay(currentDay);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    //finish();
    //overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    startActivity(intent);

    MediaPlayer mymedia = MediaPlayer.create(MondayRoutineEdit.this, R.raw.clearroutine);
    mymedia.start();
}
```

}

```
public void deleteRoutineForCurrentDay(String selectedDay)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + RoutineTable + " WHERE DayOfWeek ='" + selectedDay + "'");
}
```

Comment: As a side note, I would be EXTREMELY careful when including code in your projects such as the deleteRoutineForCurrentDate() method. That method enables SQL injection, and depending on how the method is called determines whether or not injection is possible. I'd recommend parameterized SQL objects such as stored procedures instead.

Comment: Please stop tagging all your questions `android-studio`! The IDE is **totally irrelevant**.

Comment: @CaitLANJenner Hello thanks for the advice. However do I need the commented out code? Is it important? Sorry new to android!

Comment: Just because it works without the commented code doesn't mean that excluding the code is proper nor does it follow standards. I'm certain it's there for good reasons. It appears the usage is for performing late runtime binding between the code in different applications. Please refer to this article for more details: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: "my project" and "I'm not sure what their purpose is" is bit of a contradiction. How did this code get into your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `//intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);`

Here's what [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) says:-

> If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will
>   prevent the system from applying an activity transition animation to
>   go to the next activity state.

You may wish to have a look at this [Android - How to stop animation between activity changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670754/android-how-to-stop-animation-between-activity-changes).

I'd suggest that in normal circumstances omitting this is not an issue. However, the decision could depend upon how you cam about coding the above. If you basically copied an App, then there is likely good reason why the codes was used. if you are copying part of the code then the it could well be best to omit.

2. `//finish();`

If you use the above it will remove the activity from the stack, which could cause you issues e.g. using the back button WILL NOT take you back to this activity (as it now doesn't exist on the stack) and could be confusing to the end user. If you basically copied the entire App then it may have been included for a good reason. If you just copied the block of code or based your code on seeing this, then you would probably want to omit this.

You may wish to have a look at [finish](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29), along with the rest of Activity.

3. `//overridePendingTransition(0, 0);` this is discussed in the Android - How to stop animation between activity changes. link above. You may also wish to have a look at [overridePendingTransition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29).

Whether to omit or not is basically the same and perhaps dependent upon the source of the code.